Can I use Leverless Limit Switches with a Resistive Rating of 240 VDC on an Operating Motor circuit that runs at 250 VDC?
I'm a current Electrical Engineering student working on a project where I am trying to control a motor that runs on 250 VDC, it uses proximity limit switches to control throttle valves. The maximum rating for the switches according to the manufacturers is 240 VDC.
The current limit switches used for these motors are mechanical, is it possible to replace them with these new switches?
Any input or advice would be appreciated as I am new to this topic and I can provide further information if needed, I just don't know where to start! Thanks in advance.

Please list a block diagram and put model numbers or part numbers in your post.

Is there any problem in running the motor from 235 VDC?

240 < 250 so no.
If it’s a one-off supervised test, I wouldn’t worry, but it it goes into a product you intend to sell, it’s at the very least a liability and possibly violation of CE, UL or similar.

It would be used on an industrial scale and could be a potential issue. To be more specific I don't think I can post drawings, but each throttle valve currently has 9 mechanical limit switches and the throttle valve operating motor is rated at 250VDC and the switch system I intend to replace with is linked: https://shop.process-tech.com/Product/s/1VLVl/DEFENDER-Turbine-Trip-Monitor

I wouldn’t dare to put it in production. Moreover, if rated for example 220-240 V AC, intended for mains application, it would come with margins guaranteed from standards. For DC, other standards may apply and 250 V rating could be the absolute max. I would look for something rated ideally 25+ % higher than your worst case max voltage.
